# Error with JunitTest: Would love advice and suggestion on my code

Tags: java, junit, assert

I have some problem when trying to do the 2nd test in my Junit as my questions stated:

ABC
ABC 
ABC
ABC

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the sixth element in the 2nd test case - you are accessing the fourth. Look at your array indexes.

Comment: Oh my, sorry for the dumb question! And thank you so much for pointing it out for me!

Answer (score 0):

in the testSubjects1 method, you are accessing the fourth element instead of the sixth element. I guess you have copied the content from testSubjects and paste it to testSubjects1 and changed namings. it is a quite common mistake.

Comment: @レン  if those answer really solve your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.